# send data to new screen in flutter but don't know how to set this

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, show

I am new in development but don't know how to send the data to the new screen in flutter I want to show the list of movies in the card and when I click on any card it shows the details of the movie on the new screen I am very thankful if anyone helps me

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation

Answer (score 1):

```
// you can have stateful or stateless. This depends on you
class YouScreenName extends StatefulWidget{
  final data;
  YourScreenName({this.data});
}
```

```
Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => YourScreenName(
                  data : data
                )));
```

or

```
Navigator.of(context).pushedNamed('/your_route', arguments:data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to pass the data into the constructor of the new page , and into the new page you take data from constructor and display it .